# Javascript Caching Issue

Tags: caching, browser

I am facing Javascript caching issue even though I append version number in javascript include

i.e. I am trying to force browser to load new javascript like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/aa/bbb/test.js?v=7"></script>
```

but still I am seeing old javascript being loaded by browser.

Can anyone suggest alternative fix for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that `test.js?v=7` returns the new javascript?

Comment: add timestamp in import statement to make import request unique so that browser will not cache.

Answer (score 0):

Deactivate the cache in your browser.