# Javascript Cache Issue

Tags: javascript, caching, versioning

I name my javascript files with an md5 hash of the content. So, if there is an update of the file, the filename will change.

Could someone explain why browsers are still refering to an "old" filename, until I force the browser to load the new file? (F5,...).

The problem in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770412/javascript-caching-issue) seems identical, but I think the mentioned solution will not fix the problem ("Deactivate the cache in your browser.").

Thanks!

Comment: Probably because the **page** is already cached (which contanis the reference to your file).

Comment: add timestamp in import statement so that request will be unique everytime and browser will not cache

Comment: **I already checked the HTML response headers:**

Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0

Connection:Keep-Alive

Content-Type:text/html

Date:Wed, 25 Feb 2015 08:36:51 GMT

Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT

Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100

Pragma:no-cache

Server:Apache

Transfer-Encoding:chunked

So why the page is still cached?